# Расположить растягивающиеся инпуты по правому краю

Tags: html, css, input

Проблема в выравнивании с текстом, надо чтоб растягивающиеся `input-ы` были расположены по правому краю и одной ширины, но из-за текста они смещаются и выходит криво, вытаскивать описание из `span`  или писать описание в самом `span` без использования `p` не помогает.

[Вот оригинал](https://jsfiddle.net/cbLo5b0c/2/)

```css
.filter {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #72879c;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.description-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.input {
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-flex {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">IP adsress</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">Subnet mask</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">Gateway</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">DNS server 1</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">DNS server 2</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте фиксированную ширину:

```css
.filter {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #72879c;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.description-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width:150px;
}

.input {
  height: 34px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-flex {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">IP adsress</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">Subnet mask</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">Gateway</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">DNS server 1</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<span class="filter">
        <p class="description-left">DNS server 2</p>
        <input class="input input-flex" type="text">
      </span>
<hr>
```

Comment: Помогло, и text-align заработал, спасибо большое 